# I passed I had passed I gave I have given

Tags: past-tense

Should I use "the teacher" or "a teacher" if I mention them for the first time and past perfect instead of past simple in "I gave" "I had given", "I passed it" or "I had passed it"?

"To reduce stress, I listen to music. I took a very important test the other day. To relax, I took a deep breath and read again what I wrote. After I gave/had given the test to the teacher, I was completely sure that I had passed it."

Comment: As a British English speaker I would say _had given. The teacher_ implies 'the one who had set the test'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, but saying "gave"  "passed" instead of "had passed" isn't wrong, is it?

Comment: An American might use _gave_. I don't find _I passed it_ to be idiomatic here; others may think differently.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, could you tell me if starting a sentence with "to reduce stress", "to relax" sounds natural?

Comment: That's a completely different question, and sounds like proofreading anyway!

Comment: @Kate Bunting, it's the same grammar and word and tense choice question to me. But OK. Thanks.

Comment: @Kate Bunting,  in this sentence is it again the difference between BrE and AmE English. Can I say both "I wrote" and "I had written"? "To relax, I took a deep breath and read again what I wrote."

Comment: See Andy's answer from the American point of view. I wasn't sure because I know Americans sometimes use the simple past when I would use a perfect tense ("I just had lunch").

Answer (score 1):

**"The" vs "a"**: Yes, you could say "the teacher," even if you had never mentioned them directly before, because in this case the context clarifies. If you and I were having a conversation and, in the middle of it, I blurted out "The bus driver was terrible," you would have no idea what I was talking about. If I said it as I was getting off a bus, the context is provided and the definite article is not confusing. In this case, talking about a classroom context implies the presence of a teacher, and it's reasonable to use the definite article for them as if they'd been directly mentioned.

**Simple past vs past perfect**: Past perfect is the most logical and natural choice, and I don't know that there's any regional usage involved. "*After I had given the test to the teacher, I was sure...*": Your sure-ness takes place after your giving. That's exactly what the past perfect is for: describing things that happen *before* something else that's already in the past tense. If you wanted to change your story to: "*As I gave my test to the teacher, I was sure...*" ... then the simple past would be appropriate because you completely changed the order of events: your sure-ness and your giving are simultaneous.

Comment: do you mean in all three sentences past perfect is the usual choice? I mean  in  "I had written" instead  of I wrote",  "I had given",  and "I had passed". "To relax, I took a deep breath and read again what I wrote. After I gave/had given the test to the teacher, I was completely sure that I had passed it."

Comment: @AntoniaA Think about the timeline. For some of these verbs, you're not suggesting the past perfect, but would keep them in simple past tense ("I **took** a deep breath and **read again**... I **was** sure"). For anything that happened *before* these moments, use past perfect.

Comment: yes, what "I had written" happened before too. I would use the past perfect, then.  But do AmE speakers use it less often?

Comment: @AntoniaA As an AmE speaker, I'm not aware of any reluctance to use past perfect. I guess I could imagine someone (mistakenly) using simple in these sentences, but past perfect would not be unusual or un-idiomatic.